# How to remove span from rewrite result in a field view?

Tags: 7, views, entities

In a custom view I have several fields excluded from display.
I wanted to use their values within an `global:fieldset` with rewrite output option.
This works but the values are embedded in a `<span>` that I don't want, and I didn't find the way to remove it. i.e. if rewrite text use the replacement patterns [field1],[field2],[field3] I got as result

```
<span>field1 result, field2 result, field3 result</span>
```

instead of only: 
`field1 result, field2 result, field3 result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to click on the fields you excluded (one by one), click on **Style settings** and select **Customize field HTML**. Then select `-None-` under **HTML Element**. You may need to do this for Customize label and Customize wrapper. Click Apply. Don't forget to click Save.

[image]

**EDIT:** Since you have now clarified that you are using [Views Fieldsets](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fieldsets) (and for next time, be sure to provide **ALL details** about your problem!), I believe you will need to override the default tpl.php file for the Views Fieldset fields.

Views Fieldset provides default tpl.php files inside the `template` folder inside the module folder (usually found in `/sites/all/modules/views_fieldset`. You need to copy the content of that file, save it in your theme's template folder and modify it. Follow the steps in this [general tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-templates/) (you will need to adapt it to your problem) to **override** the default template for Views Fieldset fields.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not work, I still have the span around the alter text. I edited my question to show it better.

Comment: Where are you trying to rewrite the fields? Are you creating a `Global: Custom text`? If so, you will ALSO need to customize the style for that custom text field (the SPAN is probably coming from that custom field)

Comment: I rewrite the field `Global:fieldset` that does not provide the possibility to customize the style.  But when I look at the code of this module I do not find where a span is added.

Comment: See my edited answer now.

Comment: Thanks for you edited comment and help. I already overided this template without success because the content of the rewriten global:fieldset (the result)  is provided in the `$legend` variable. The content of $legend is embeded within the span tag that I want to avoid. A solution would be to remove it by extracting this tag from the $legend variable directly within the template tpl file. I expected that some one may explain me from where this span tag comes and how to remove it.